# How to hide a model in multi model view in a grid-like pattern like .isolate does | Forge viewer API

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Currently im working on the web based multi model viewer from the autodesk forge api. Im trying to implement a filter which only shows object with a specific property value e.g. 'window'. To filter the models and isolate the objects using the extracted dbdis works fine, the problem starts when a model does not have a single object with the asked value. Because then it does not become transparent. You can hide it using

```
viewer.hide(node, model)
```

But then the model completely disappears. Is there a way to hide the model in the same fashion

```
viewer.isolate(node, model)
```

does?

This was my first attempt:
(Quick side note: The ID's are NOT unique to all models loaded e.g.: The door from model 1 and stair from model 2 could have the same ID)

```
function objectIsolation(searchTerm, modelInstance) {
  modelInstance.search(searchTerm, function(dbIds) {
    if (!dbIds.length) {
      viewer.isolate(tempDbIds, modelInstance);
    }
    else {
      viewer.isolate(dbIds, modelInstance);
      tempDbIds = dbIds[0];
    }
  });
}
```

This attempt obviously leaves one unwanted object visible. And if I replace

```
viewer.isolate(tempDbIds, modelInstance);
```

with

```
viewer.hide(model);
```

The model completely disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the [isolate](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#isolate-node-model) method accepts **object IDs** (also called **dbIDs**), and *not* models. The optional second parameter is used to specify which model you're referring to.

With that said, you can do something like `viewer.isolate(1, modelA)` or `viewer.hide(1, modelA)` to isolate or hide an entire model because the root of each model typically has the object ID set to 1.

Comment: I know that the isolate method technically does not accept models, but for some reason it actually works for me (Maybe they updated the function but didn't include it in the documentation?). Anyhow I tried it using viewer.isolate(1, modelA), but this does not work in my case.

Comment: Btw `viewer.isolate(1, modelA)` will _show_ the entire model, and `viewer.hide(1, modelA)` will _hide_ the entire model.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution!

You are actually able to isolate models from each other. Therefore you can exchange

```
viewer.isolate(tempDbIds, modelInstance)
```

with

```
viewer.isolate(tempModel, modelInstance)
```

**tempModel** in that case would e.g. the model that was loaded previously. This obvioulsy needs some more logic but it fixes the main problem of isolating an entire model upon having no qualified object.